# Data always count as duplicate even if the data is unique

Tags: sql-server

I Have a table like this

```
insert into dbo.SOME_TABLE
    ([Posting Id],[Trade Id],[Effective Date])
values
    ('76342449','146409','20210202')
,('94813027','140863','20210520')
,('76445565','140212','20210202')
,('94073803','159953','20210517')
```

[image: table]

and i want to know if there is a duplicate data,so i put another column to make it unique

```
select [Posting Id]
,[Trade Id]
,[Effective Date]
,concat([posting id],'-',[trade id]) from dbo.SOME_TABLE
```

[image: uniqueid]

but when i make a query,all data always shows its duplicate even when i check it manually all data is unique. the expected result are there is no data (all columns NULL).

what is wrong with my query?

```
select top (10)
    [posting id]
    ,[Trade Id]
    ,left(convert(varchar(10),[Effective Date],112),8) [Effective Date]
    ,concat([posting id],'-',[trade id]) UNIQUEID 
from dbo.SOME_TABLE
    where [Effective Date]  BETWEEN '20210101' and '20210520'
group by [Posting Id]
,[Trade Id]
,left(convert(varchar(10),[Effective Date],112),8)
,concat([posting id],'-',[trade id])
having 
    COUNT(concat([posting id],'-',[trade id]))>1
```

Comment: Don't post data as images, we can't use it. Take the time to post it as DDL and DML statements, or *at least* as well formatted tabular `text`. As for the question, what are the expected results here?

Comment: What does this return? `SELECT [posting id], count(*) from dbo.SOME_TABLE GROUP BY [posting id] HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`

Comment: @Larnu im sorry sir,the expecting result is null..because there is no duplicate data

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid it return count column as 2 
like this

|posting id | count |
75817745  | 2        |
56215025  | 2        |

Comment: `select * from dbo.SOME_TABLE where [posting id]=75817745`  will show you one of the duplicates

Comment: Posting random data that has NO duplicates will not help others understand your issue. And posting data that is not sorted does not help anyone - including yourself - visualize whatever issue you think you have. The few rows of sample data you did post are unique - which also does not help anyone. Lastly, concatenating values from a row does not magically generate a unique value for each row. You need to post real examples of duplicate values for anyone to help.

Answer (score 0):

visit https://learnsql.com/blog/how-to-find-duplicate-values-in-sql/
to find duplicates values from SQL tables

Answer (score 0):

I think your data is already having duplicates. First try to eliminate duplicates and then go for generation of unique IDs.

Sample code below to figure out duplicates in your data.

```sql
declare @some_table table([PostingId] bigint,[TradeId] int,[EffectiveDate] date)
insert into @sOME_TABLE
    ([PostingId],[TradeId],[EffectiveDate])
values
    ('76342449','146409','20210202')
,('94813027','140863','20210520')
,('76445565','140212','20210202')
,('94073803','159953','20210517')
,('76342449','146409','20210302')


SELECT t.* FROM
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PostingId,tradeId ORDER BY effectiveDate) as rnk
from @some_table) as t
where rnk > 1
```

| PostingId | TradeId | EffectiveDate | rnk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 76342449 | 146409 | 2021-03-02 | 2 |

Comment: i cant show you the real table due to a sensitive data in there.....but,that is why i create "UNIQUEID" columns that contains combinations between another data columns to make it  unique.

for example in your sample

even if the data in date 2021-03-02 is same as data in 2021-02-02
but it will show no duplicate if 
uniqueid = 76342449-146409-20210302 || 76342449-146409-20210202